# What is wrong with this code for Candy I?

Tags: c

I am stuck at a problem on spoj.Here is the ideone link for the source code for you to test your edits: http://ideone.com/IGrTjK and the link for the problem is: http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY/ It appears to give me WA on spoj despite passing given test cases with correct format. Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int n, i, sum, avg, count;
    while(1) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n == -1) 
            break;
        unsigned int a[n+1];
        sum = count = 0;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            sum += a[i];
        }
        if(sum%n != 0) {
            printf("-1\n");
        }
        else {
            avg = sum/n;
            for(i=0; a[i]<avg; i++)
            count += (avg - a[i]);
            printf("%d\n", count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Incorrect loop

Your main loop ends at the first packet that is equal or larger than the average:

> ```
>    for(i=0;a[i]<avg;i++)
>       count+=(avg-a[i]);
> ```

It needs to look through all packets:

```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
      if (a[i] < avg)
          count+=(avg-a[i]);
   }
```

Comment: it should be if(a[i] < avg) instead of if(a[i] > avg) i think

Comment: @user132458 Yeah I got confused because in my mind I was doing it the other way (looking for packets larger than average instead of smaller).  Thanks.